# How can an SQL query return data from multiple tables?

Tags: java, sql, resultset

How can an SQL query return data from multiple tables?
for ex. my sql query suppose to list all students in specific classroom
but instead it shows only 1 student. Can this be done by system output?

```
if (forms.Validation.textNotEmpty(tfId)) {
    try {
        ResultSet rs = hogDB.getData("select * from student where sleepRoom = ("+tId.getText()+");");

        if (rs.next()) {
            tfStudentId1.setText(rs.getString("student_id"));
            tfForNamne1.setText(rs.getString("fornamne"));
            tfAfterNamne1.setText(rs.getString("AfterNamn"));
            tfSleep1.setText(rs.getString("sleepRoom"));

        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I advice coding using English variable names, column names, etc. Especially if you plan to ask questions on international boards. We need more information. What is the data model and population? What have you tried yourself?

Comment: Do you have multiple text fields to show multiple results?  Also, change it from `if (rs.next()) {` to `while (rs.next()) {`

Comment: To specify fields from another table, prefix with the table name, e.g. `SELECT elevhem.ELEVHEM_ID...`.

Comment: @MarkBaijens there!

Comment: Did you try to debug?  The query _might_ actually be returning multiple rows.  However, within the `if` block, a row is assigned to the **same** variables.  There needs to be `List`, and create a new object for each row, and add to the `List`. You need to loop over all rows as @SteveSmith suggested.

Comment: @SteveSmith yes i have multiple text fields but not enough because i don't know how much rows it will return :(

Comment: @MarkBaijens, rather than coding in English always I suggest coding in your favourite langauge. Then when you need to ask a question on an English speaking site, don’t post any of your real code but an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in English.

Comment: @SteveSmith i changed it to while but still same problem! can it be done by system output instead of text fields?

Comment: How had you expected to see all your students? Please be more precise about desired or expected results.

Comment: `System.out.println()` should tell you each student retrieved from the database so you can tell how many they are. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

To find out whether you are really retrieving just one student or several, here’s a suggestion for a piece of test code.

```
        try {
            ResultSet rs = hogDB.getData("select * from student where sleepRoom = ("
                                            + tId.getText() + ");");

            int count = 0;
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.format("%-10s%-20s%-20s%-8s%n", 
                        rs.getString("student_id"), rs.getString("fornamne"), 
                        rs.getString("AfterNamn"), rs.getString("sleepRoom"));
                count++;
            }
            System.out.println("" + count + " students retrieved");
        } catch(Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Another possible issue, is `tId.getText()` a number? If it isn’t, you should probably enclose it in single quotes in the query. In any case, the recommended way is to pass a value to the database is through a `?` placeholder and some `setXx()` call on the prepared statement.